# Double quotes appear when it should've been single quotes Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently doing exercices from the book "Learn Python the hard way by Zed, Shaw. "
Although the author specified that his book is intended for Python 2.x, I'm managing to convert the syntax from the book to python 3 standards.

One strange thing, though. In an exercise where he's explaining the different uses of %r, the interpreter prints one of the string values with double quotes, whereas the others are printed with a single quote.
I'd like to know the reason, please.

Here's the code :

```
formatter = " %r %r %r %r"
print (formatter % ( "I had this thing",
   "That you could type up right.",
   "But it didn't sing.",
   "So I said goodnight."))
```

The code works fine, it's just that in the interpreter, the output reads :

> 'I had this thing', 'That you could type up right.' "But I didn't sing." 'So I said good night.'

As you can see, the third value gets printed inside double quotes. How come ?

I'm using notepad ++, python 3 and Windows Powhershell.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"But it didn't sing."** as this string contains single quote, it is being printed inside double quote.

Moreover, %r will insert the canonical string representation of the object (i.e. repr(o))

To learn more about **repr()** read Python3 official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr

Comment: But of course ! I should have thought of it.  There's already an apostrophe for the did not contraction, so it has to use the double quotes.  Thank you [ :